# Can I buy a domain from myself if WHOIS privacy is enabled?

Tags: domains, whois, domain-transfer

I have a domain with Hosting Company A, and I want to move it to Hosting Company B. I have tried to disable the WHOIS privacy on Hosting Company A's web application, but it appears not to have worked. I also cannot even reach Hosting Company A. When I run the command-line `whois` program, I see that the WHOIS database has been updated, yet the private information is still there. I need WHOIS privacy disabled to transfer the domain, according to Hosting Company B. Would purchasing the domain from myself through Hosting Company B be an option? Can I purchase the domain from myself to transfer it, since Company A is effectively keeping it hostage?

Comment: Registry privacy has nothing to do with changing hosts. You can change hosts anytime. It is a shame that you cannot contact your current hosting company. Set up the new hosting account, log into your registrars control panel and change the domain IP address to the one your new host provides. Deploy your site to the new host. That is it! It will take up to 48 hours for the DNS changes to propagate throughout the Internet. I would make sure your current/old hosting company cannot charge you again after the transfer.

Comment: @closetnoc you are right to some extent, but the problem is that with privacy, when sending the EPP code, the registrant doesn't receive it.

Comment: Don't you own the domain? There is something missing.

Comment: Even your title is confusing to me. Why would you need to buy a domain from yourself? Can you clarify this for us??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check that the domain company is not a reseller.  If they are, contact the company they buy domains from, the registrar.

If you are getting no satisfaction from the primary registrar, lodge a complaint with ICANN - they can sort this sort of thing out.

Comment: Even though this question is completely confusing, I appreciate your answer. For example, the OP is talking about changing hosts, but is talking like he is changing registrars. Which is it?

Comment: Yep...I figured it was a terminology thing and did my best :o)